# Converse of Wiener's lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a commutative Banach algebra with unit. 
It is well known that if the Gelfand transform $\hat{x}$ of $x\in A$ is non-zero, then $x$ is invertible in $A$ (the so called Wiener Lemma in the case when $A$ is the Banach algebra of absolutely convergent Fourier series).

As a converse of the above, let $B$ be a Banach space contained in $A$ and suppose $B$ is closed under inversion - i.e.: If $x\in B$ and $x^{-1}\in A$ then $x^{-1}\in B$.

(1) Prove that $B$ is a Banach algebra.

(2) Must $A$ and $B$ have the same norm? If not are the norms similar?

(3) Do $A$ and $B$ have the same maximal ideal space?

Comment: I don't think (1) is true. Pick any Banach algebra $A$ with a noninvertible element $f$ whose square $f^2$ is not a multiple of $f$ and consider the subspace spanned by $f$.

Comment: I do not understand 1) how these statements constitute a converse of what you have written, and 2) what the first two questions mean.  Do you mean that B is a Banach subalgebra of A?  And I don't know what "same" norm means.

Comment: Akhil Mathew: You are right!! I forgot to say that the unit of $A$ belongs to $B$.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: 1) I see why you ask - for a given Banach algebra the converse of Wiener's Lemma is obvious if an element is invertible then $\hat{x}$ is non-zero. To see what I mean I suggest the to phrase it like this:  Wieners Lemma states that IF you work in a commutative unitary Banach algebra THEN the necessary condition of inversion implies inversion. Here we say that inversion in $B$ implies that $B$ is a Banach algebra - provided there is a larger Banach algebra $A$ where inversion really takes place.\\

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: 
2) Same norm would be: $\|x\|_B =\|x\|_A$ for all $x\in B$.\\ Similar norm would be: $C_1\|x\|_B \leq \|x\|_A\leq C_2 =\|x\|_B$  for all $x\in B$ for some uniform constants $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: Replace "Banach" with "quasi-Banach". Is it possible to deduce (1)?

Comment: When you say $B$ is a Banach space contained in $A$, do you mean that it is a linear subspace of $A$, equipped with a complete norm that is stronger than (i.e. majorizes some constant multiple of) the given norm of $A$?

Comment: @YemonChoi I do not see if that is necessary. BTW, looking at it now again I see that there are obvious counterexamples to (3) e.g. $B=\mathbb{C}$ and $A=$ "what ever"...

Comment: @YemonChoi I think any contribution is interesting, at least it might widen my knowledge :)

Comment: @AD: (3) is obviously false, *as was pointed out in Akhil Matthew's answer*

Comment: @AD: when you say "I do not see that it is necessary" - my point was that you should make it clear in your question what actual question you are asking. When you say "a Banach space $B$ contained in $A$" what do you *mean*, **precisely**?

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes, I will think over it all, perhaps I remove it all.

Comment: @YemonChoi I just re-read Akhil Mattew's answer (I read it some time ago) - and sure (3) was disproved there!

Answer (score 2):

For now, I shall assume that $B$ is a closed subspace of $A$ (and is treated simply as a topological vector space for the moment).

(1) Let $x \in B$; we need to prove that $x^2 \in B$. From this elementary algebra will imply that $B$ is closed under multiplication. Now, when $t$ is close to zero, we have $1-tx$ invertible in $A$, hence in $B$; so $1+tx + t^2x^2 + \dots$ lies in $B$ for $t$ close to zero. Taking the second derivative at $0$ (recall that $B$ is a *closed* subspace) shows that $x^2 \in B$.

I don't fully understand what you are asking in (2) yet, so:

(3) No. Take $A$ to be any Banach algebra not equal to the complex numbers and $B$ the subalgebra spanned by the identity.

Comment: Regarding (1) - Nice, but you do not really need to take the derivative to reach $x^2\in B$, in fact you do not need $B$ to be closed in $A$. 
(3) Works fine!

Comment: (Here are some proofs of the statement $x^2\in B$: Put $f(z)=(1−zx)^{−1}$, and look at --- 1) $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(re^{it})e^{−2it}dt$. --- 2) $(f(z)+f(-z)-2)/2z^2$, and let $z\to0$. --- 3) $(f(z)-1-zx)/z^2$, and let $z\to0$.)

Comment: AD: I'm not sure you can define integrals unless you are working with a closed subspace.

Comment: In a Banach space you can, look up the Bochner integral. In complete linear spaces there are sort of Riemann integrals discovered by S. Rolewicz (but these are strange and must be handled gently).

Answer (score 2):

I think the OP needs to give a *precise* formulation of what he/she means by "a Banach space inside a Banach algebra", because this affects the answers to the questions in non-trivial ways.

Contrary to what the OP seems to claim in comments to Akhil Matthew's answer, if $B$ is not closed in $A$, then it can be an inverse-closed subspace without the given Banach norm on $B$ being submultiplicative. However, by Akhil's argument, $B$ is a subalgebra of $A$.

It is still not clear to me what precisely is meant by (2). So I shall just point out for the record that if we let $A({\mathbb T})$ be the space of all continuous functions ${\mathbb T}\to {\mathbb C}$ with absolutely convergent Fourier series, equipped with pointwise product, this is a Banach algebra and it is a unital subalgebra of $C({\mathbb T})$. Clearly the norm on $A({\mathbb T})$ is not equivalent to the sup-norm inherited from $C({\mathbb T})$; but $A({\mathbb T})$ is inverse-closed in $C({\mathbb T})$, by Gelfand's version of Wiener's $1/f$ lemma.

Note also in (3) that one can have commutative, semisimple, unital Banach algebras $A$ and $B$, and an injective, contractive, unital algebra homomorphism $B\to A$ with dense range, such that $A$ and $B$ have different maximal ideal spaces. The example I have in mind is due, I think, to Honary, but I am out of the office right now and can't look this up.